# CFLDAP Authentication failed Password

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

I am trying some code using `cfldap` in ColdFusion. The problem is when I try using a password that includes a `#`, I get an error:

> Authentication failed:[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece ]

Is it possible to use a cfldap password containing `#`? I've tried with `ReplaceNoCase`. When the password has a `#`, it changes to `##`, so ColdFusion knows it is a text, not a variable, but still get this error. Thank you so much guys.

Here's my code

```
<cfset convertPwd = ReplaceNoCase(txtPassword,"##","####")>
<cfldap action="QUERY"
    name="ChkUserName"
    attributes="sAMAccountName,givenName,initials,sn,cn,mail,objectClass,dn"
    start="#trim(qGetSettingLdap.bindserver)#"
    server="#trim(qGetSettingLdap.ipserver)#"
    scope="SUBTREE"
    username="#form.txtName#"
    password="#trim(convertPwd)#" 
    port="#trim(qGetSettingLdap.portserver)#" filter="(sAMAccountName=#form.txtName#)">
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping with  `##` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler, you should present that as the answer.

Comment: Based on the question, I don't think that is it. The `ReplaceNoCase()` is exactly what I would try.

Comment: What led you to conclude the `#` is the cause? That should not be an issue as pound signs *within* a variable do not get evaluated. Not unless the value is literally hard coded in the .cfm/cfc file. A quick search suggests other possibilities, such as the [format of the username](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/230992?start=0&tstart=0). What is the format of `#form.txtName#`?